# Feature Importance and Model Score

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, random-forest

Hi I was doing a practice on Random Forest Classifier using a credit card fraud dataset from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud).

First, I created model with 20 trees and fitted it into the full dataset (31 features), the model was able to get a score of around 99.95%. Subsequently, I checked the feature importance and it seems like feature 12, 14 and 17 was measured to be the most important features.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.25)
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20, verbose=2)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
model.score(x_test, y_test)
================================================================
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  20 out of  20 | elapsed:    0.2s finished
0.999592708069998
================================================================
importance = model.feature_importances_
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
================================================================
Feature: 0, Score: 0.01206
Feature: 1, Score: 0.01748
Feature: 2, Score: 0.01454
Feature: 3, Score: 0.02275
Feature: 4, Score: 0.02935
Feature: 5, Score: 0.01019
Feature: 6, Score: 0.01946
Feature: 7, Score: 0.03668
Feature: 8, Score: 0.01059
Feature: 9, Score: 0.03032
Feature: 10, Score: 0.07120
Feature: 11, Score: 0.09098
Feature: 12, Score: 0.10580
Feature: 13, Score: 0.01147
Feature: 14, Score: 0.12103
Feature: 15, Score: 0.01332
Feature: 16, Score: 0.04959
Feature: 17, Score: 0.14742
Feature: 18, Score: 0.04764
Feature: 19, Score: 0.01404
Feature: 20, Score: 0.01091
Feature: 21, Score: 0.01968
Feature: 22, Score: 0.01265
Feature: 23, Score: 0.01125
Feature: 24, Score: 0.00876
Feature: 25, Score: 0.00678
Feature: 26, Score: 0.02034
Feature: 27, Score: 0.00833
Feature: 28, Score: 0.01272
Feature: 29, Score: 0.01267
```

I wanted to see how would the important features affect the model score and thus I went to drop a bunch of features to see what happens. However I realised that even after dropping all but feature 0 (which only has an importance of 0.01), the model score still remained very high (94%)

```
tiny_x_train = x_train.copy()
tiny_x_test = x_test.copy()
tiny_x_train.drop(df.columns.difference(['V1']), 1, inplace=True) #Feature 0 is V1
tiny_x_test.drop(df.columns.difference(['V1']), 1, inplace=True)
model.fit(tiny_x_train, y_train)
model.score(tiny_x_test, tiny_y_test)
================================================================
0.9473684210526315
```

I am guessing part of the reason why the score remained high was due to the data being very skewed (fraud happens in <1% of data). Is my assumption correct or is there anything else I have missed out here?

Answer (score 0):

**You are correct.**

You are obtaining such a good accuracy because of dataset. For sure, if you check other scores of the confusion matrix (precision, recall,...) you will see that your model is not as a good as it seems.

As a final comment, imagine I create a model that always returns: "No Fraud". Which will be the accuracy of this silly model? Around 99%. So I recommend check the confusion matrix metrics to understand better the behavior of your model.